# because the following virtual functions are pure within a class

Tags: c++, abstract

I have the following code which I am trying to compile. at first everything was ok. I did some modifications and then I got the following errors. I really really don't understand what is happening:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:38:32: error: cannot declare variable 'mp' to be of abstract type 'MasterPricerContentManager'
     MasterPricerContentManager mp(&query);
                                ^
main.cpp:20:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'MasterPricerContentManager':
 class MasterPricerContentManager: public ContentManager {
       ^
main.cpp:17:24: note:   virtual std::string* ContentManager::getAnswer()
   virtual std::string *getAnswer()   = 0;
```

From what I understand if a function is virtual pure i have to implement it in the derived class. why i am getting that problem?

---

```
/******************************************************************************

                              Online C++ Compiler.
               Code, Compile, Run and Debug C++ program online.
Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to compile and execute it.

*******************************************************************************/

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ContentManager {
 public:
  virtual bool execute()= 0;
  virtual void setQuery(std::string *query) = 0;
  virtual std::string *getAnswer()   = 0;
};

class MasterPricerContentManager: public ContentManager {
 public:
   explicit MasterPricerContentManager(std::string *query):_query(query) {}
    ~MasterPricerContentManager() {}
    MasterPricerContentManager(const MasterPricerContentManager &)= delete;

    bool execute() {return true;}
    void setQuery(std::string  *query) {_query = query; }
    std::string       *getAnswer() const { return {}; }

  private:
    std::string * _query;

};

int main()
{  
    std::string query = "hello";
    MasterPricerContentManager mp(&query);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the const keyword on the `MasterPricerContentManager::getAnswer()` making it not override the pure virtual method? Try removing it/adding const to the parent class

Comment: I suggest get into habit of using `override` keyword with all the virtual functions you intend to override. Helps spot errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why i am getting that problem?

Because the signature in your base class is different from the one in your subclass:

```
 virtual std::string *getAnswer()   = 0;
```

vs

```
 std::string       *getAnswer() const { return {}; }
```

You need to either add the `const` modifier to the declaration in the base class, or remove it from the override in the subclass.

Answer (score 6):

When you override the function, the signature has to have *exactly* the same type. Even slight perturbations will cause it to not count as an override. In your case we have

```
virtual std::string *getAnswer()   = 0;
std::string *getAnswer() const { ... }
```

You need to remove the `const`.

If you're using C++11 or newer, consider adding an `override` annotation to the end of methods intended as an override. Then you'll get more specific errors if something like this happens, and you can catch it earlier.

```
std::string *getAnswer() const override { ... }
```

Comment: `override` is a great way to detect this kind of problem